# How to create a comment and reply section with MERN STACK

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I created a comment session on my entertainment website

It’s working on backend.

It’s working on the frontend also but it’s not displaying the content the user typed on the database

This is my frontend (Comment form) logic:

```
 export default function AddComment({ busy}) {
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");
  const { movieId } = useParams();
  const { updateNotification } = useNotification();

  const handleOnChange = ({ target }) => {
    setContent(target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { error, message } = await addComment(movieId);
    if (error) return updateNotification("error", error);

    updateNotification("success", message);
    const newComment = {
      content,
    };

    setContent(newComment);
    setContent("");
  };

  return (
    <div className='p-5'>
      <br />
      <p className='dark:text-white text-primary'>replies</p>
      <hr className='w-64' />
      {/* Comment Lists */}

      {/* Root Comment Form */}

      {/* Form */}
      <form className='flex ' onSubmit={handleSubmit} busy={busy}>
        <textarea
          value={content}
          onChange={handleOnChange}
          type='text'
          autoComplete='text'
          className='w-full rounded-md p-2 dark:text-white text-primary outline-none bg-transparent resize-none border-b focus:border-blue-500'
          placeholder='Add New comment'
        />
        <br className='dark:text-white text-primary ' />
        <button
          type='submit'
          className=' w-5 h-14 dark:text-white text-primary bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-400 focus:border-blue-900 rounded-md'
        >
          {busy ? <ImSpinner3 className='animate-spin' /> : "Add"}
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then the addComment is coming from this API:

```
import { catchError, getToken } from "../utils/helper";
import client from "./client";

export const addComment = async (movieId, newComment) => {
  const token = getToken();
  try {
    const { data } = await client.post(
      `/comments/comment/${movieId}`,
      newComment,
      {
        headers: {
          authorization: "Bearer " + token,
        },
      }
    );
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    return catchError(error);
  }
};
```

The backend is working:

```
exports.createComment = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { movieId } = req.params;
  const { content } = req.body;
  const userId = req.user._id;
  console.log(req.body);

  //   verify user before comment
  if (!req.user.isVerified)
    return sendError(res, "Please verify your email first!");
  if (!isValidObjectId(movieId)) return sendError(res, "Invalid Movie!");

  //   create and update new comment
  const newComment = new Comment({
    user: userId,
    parentMovie: movieId,
    content,
  });

  // save new comment

  await newComment.save();

  res.json({ message: "New comment added!!", newComment });
});
```

I posted with Postman on backend it gave me this on the database:

```
_id
:
62dcfccd93444cef55611632
user
:
62bf20d65073a7c65f549078
parentMovie
:
62c2c425465804ff32cdd06c
content
:
"hello"
createdAt
:
2022-07-24T08:03:25.666+00:00
updatedAt
:
2022-07-24T08:03:25.666+00:00
__v
:
0
```

on the console:

```
The port is listening on port 8000
connected to db
{ content: 'hello' }
POST /api/comments/comment/62c2c425465804ff32cdd06c 200 447.534 ms - 260
```

I posted on the frontend it gave me this on the database, no content:

```
_id
:
62dcfd6993444cef55611635
user
:
62bf57e8a8f3e737b2af23d9
parentMovie
:
62cc1d426785cfe42f8737a8
createdAt
:
2022-07-24T08:06:01.458+00:00
updatedAt
:
2022-07-24T08:06:01.458+00:00
__v
:
0
```

on the console it shows an empty object:

```
{}
POST /api/comments/comment/62cc1d426785cfe42f8737a8 200 364.009 ms - 242
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem

**Hope this solution will help many**

```
 const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { error, message } = await addComment(movieId, content); // call the content and movieId from backend
    if (error) return updateNotification("error", error);

    updateNotification("success", message);
    // push and display the content on database
    const newComment = {
      content,
    };

    setContent(newComment);
    setContent("");
  };
```

**Then the API should be like this**

```
    export const addComment = async (movieId, newComment) => {
  const token = getToken();

  // console.log(newComment);
  const body = {
    content: newComment,
  };
  try {
    const { data } = await client.post(`/comments/comment/${movieId}`, body, {
      headers: {
        authorization: "Bearer " + token,
      },
    });
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    return catchError(error);
  }
};
```